# Admixture graph with ggplot2 - arrangment of bars by an additional factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I tried to create an ordered bar plot (admixture plot) with facets as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679888/how-to-group-order-data-in-r-for-a-barplot) by @Axeman. However, instead of arranging the individuals by their corresponding clusters (pop; V1 - V4 in the example in the link), I'd like to group it by their respective species.

So, what I get is a stacked bar plot with facets whereas the facets represent the species and where the probabilities for the group assignments within the species should be ordered by the likely assignment

How do I have to adjust the R code? Any recommendations?

Here is the R code for the solution from the linked thread ...

```
library(tidyverse)

plot_data <- tbl %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  gather('pop', 'prob', V1:V4) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(likely_assignment = pop[which.max(prob)],
         assingment_prob = max(prob)) %>% 
  arrange(likely_assignment, desc(assingment_prob)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(id = forcats::fct_inorder(factor(id)))

ggplot(plot_data, aes(id, prob, fill = pop)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~likely_assignment, scales = 'free', space = 'free')
```

... and here the example data set ...

```
tbl = structure(list(V1 = c(1e-05, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.430202, 0.99997, 
0.801974, 1e-05, 0.99997, 0.99997, 1e-05, 0.999968, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
1.3e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1.8e-05, 
1e-05, 1.2e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1.1e-05, 1e-05, 0.642925, 
1e-05, 0.99997, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 1e-05, 0.99997, 
0.99997, 0.287976, 1e-05, 0.99997, 0.99997, 0.99997, 1e-05, 0.533994, 
0.99997, 0.99997, 1e-05, 0.99997, 1e-05, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
0.99997, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.307669, 0.99997, 
0.604114, 0.604792, 0.29646, 0.514252, 0.99997, 0.798616, 0.516577, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.449886, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
0.790272, 1e-05, 0.576786, 0.776731), V2 = c(0.99997, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 
0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1.2e-05, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 1e-05, 
0.99997, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.528138, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 1e-05, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.712004, 0.99997, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 0.465986, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 0.99997, 
0.99997, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.05777, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.591857, 0.99997, 1e-05, 
0.99997, 0.99997, 0.99997, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05
), V3 = c(1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.541112, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.329922, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.198006, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.999967, 0.451508, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.749225, 
1e-05, 0.99997, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.442211, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.188, 
1e-05, 0.248756, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.395866, 0.395188, 0.293429, 0.427968, 
1e-05, 0.201364, 0.483403, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.408123, 1e-05, 0.550094, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.209708, 0.533729, 0.423194, 0.223249
), V4 = c(1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 0.458868, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.670058, 
0.99997, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 0.99997, 0.569778, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 
1e-05, 0.548472, 1e-05, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 
0.471833, 1e-05, 0.250753, 0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.999969, 
1e-05, 0.357055, 0.557769, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 0.99997, 1e-05, 
0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.81198, 1e-05, 0.751224, 1e-05, 0.99997, 
0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.692311, 
1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.410101, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 0.99997, 
0.99997, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 1e-05, 
0.466251, 1e-05, 1e-05)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-93L))

species = c("fuliginosa", "fuliginosa", "fuliginosa", "fuliginosa", "fuliginosa", 
"fuliginosa", "fuliginosa", "fuliginosa", "fuliginosa", "fortis", 
"fuliginosa", "fuliginosa", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fuliginosa", 
"fuliginosa", "fortis", "scandens", "fortis", "fortis", "scandens", 
"scandens", "fuliginosa", "magnirostris", "scandens", "magnirostris", 
"fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "scandens", 
"fortis", "scandens", "scandens", "magnirostris", "fortis", "fortis", 
"fortis", "scandens", "magnirostris", "magnirostris", "fortis", 
"fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "magnirostris", "fortis", "magnirostris", 
"magnirostris", "magnirostris", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", 
"magnirostris", "magnirostris", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", 
"fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", 
"magnirostris", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", 
"fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fuliginosa", 
"fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fuliginosa", "fuliginosa", 
"fuliginosa", "fuliginosa", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", "fortis", 
"fortis", "fortis")
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it reproducible, by copying the relevant data and code from the linked question? If you just want to change the variable used for faceting, you would just need `facet_grid(~species)` instead of `facet_grid(~likely_assignment)`, but otherwise you may have to explain more about exactly what result you want.

Comment: Thanks, @Marius. Now I added the example code and another paragraph where I tried to better summarize my intents. The problem with just using ~likely assignment is that I then get many "empty" bars (I think it's a problem due to the fact that 'plot_data' is transformed to an tbl object.